How to run third-party application in IIS Server from an ASP.NET Core web application
I have an ASP.NET Core web application. My goal is to create a feature that will allow users to click a button which will open a third-party application, for instance, Adobe Photoshop, and do some tasks and return response to the user.
The approach I am following is that, I have a vbscript that instruct the server machine to open the third-party application and forward the task that the application need to do. In the C# code, I have used process.start() that executes the vbscript.
This approach is working fine in the local development computer. However, after deploying in the IIS server, the process.start() is not executing the vbscript.
After going through several thread in stack overflow, I came to know that, by default the process.start() doesn't execute in IIS server due to lack of permission.
My question is what should be the appropriate approach for this scenario?

That’s impossible with today’s web security standards, where web apps have no access to the desktop environment and apps unless you have extra bits installed on every desktops you want to manage. Hire a security consultant and you can learn more in that area.

You might read https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 to learn why your local development environment seemed to work but that’s just the illusion.

You'll really be swimming upstream if you try to make IIS launch a process, which it intentionally tries to prevent for security's sake (and to be clear, they're right that it's a bad idea). You can get around that by creating the server as a console application that is launched from your session (e.g. by running the application manually or by triggering it on login from a scheduled task), rather than by creating it as a web service that is managed by IIS. In that framework, your application can both listen for incoming web requests and launch processes that pop in Windows.
I hacked together a simple way to do this called remotewinlauncher a while back; it might be pretty close to what you want. The goal was to have a pre-defined list of programs I could start on my home box by going to myexampleurl.com/launch/appname and then later end with myexampleurl.com/kill/appname.
Relevant Program.cs snippet:
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
            .WithParsed<Options>(o =>
            {
                Secret = o.Secret;
                Path = o.Path;
                HideOnStart = o.HideOnStart;
                Title = o.Title;
            })
            .WithNotParsed<Options>((e) =>
            {
                ConsoleExtension.Show();
                Console.WriteLine("Missing arguments! Press any key to terminate.");
                Console.Read();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            });

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        builder.Configuration
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        var app = builder.Build();
        Configuration = app.Configuration;


        Console.WriteLine($"Launching on {Configuration["Urls"]}{Environment.NewLine}");
        string sampleUrl = Configuration["Urls"]?.Split(';')?[0] ?? String.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine($"Use your secret to launch the program, for example:{Environment.NewLine}{sampleUrl}/launch/<secret>");
        if (HideOnStart)
            ConsoleExtension.Hide();

        app.MapGet("/launch/", HandleLaunch);
        app.MapGet("/launch/{secret}", HandleLaunch);
        app.MapGet("/kill/", HandleKill);
        app.MapGet("/kill/{secret}", HandleKill);

        await app.RunAsync();
    }

    static string HandleLaunch(string? secret = null)
    {
        if (!ValidateSecret(secret))
            return "no";
        return Launch();
    }

    static int failAttempts = 0;
    static Process lastStartedProcess = null;
    static string Launch()
    {
        var result = ProcessFinder.GetHandleWindow(Title);
        if (result != default(IntPtr))
        {
            // Already opened
            return "already running";
        }
        if (lastStartedProcess != null && !lastStartedProcess.HasExited)
        {
            return "process still running";
        }
        lastStartedProcess = StartProcess(Path, Title);
        return "ok";
    }

    static Process StartProcess(string path, string title)
    {
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = path; 
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        process.Start();

        SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
        ProcessFinder.SetWindowText(process.MainWindowHandle, title);

        return process;
    }

Just to reiterate: this solution is a security nightmare (and so is basically any that do what you want). I tried to keep it as limited as possible, so that it has a predefined list of x-y pairs where "one instance of x app can be started or closed with y secret". You really don't want to take any raw user input from the internet and convert that into a string that is run on your box, with your permissions

Thank you so much. Your solution gave me an idea how to deal with multiple process. I have created a desktop application, which will communicate with third-party applications and my web application will give instructions to the desktop application using ICP (interprocess communication). C# supports Named-Pipes for interprocess communication, and it works fine with windows firewall. There are several other approaches to be follows in this scenario but in my case as both of the applications will be hosted under same machine, that's why I choose the Named-Pipe approach.
